# Apply value specified for date range (from, to) to value in table containing single row per date

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all, sorry for title, but my english is too poor to explain meaning of my question. :)

Let's suppose that we have two tables. The first table `tbl_percents` contains percent value history during date ranges. If date field `to` equals `0000-00-00` it means that it is unfinished range.

```
table: tbl_percents
from date
to date
percent int

example content:
2001-01-01 | 2015-01-21 | 10%
2015-01-21 | 0000-00-00 | 20%
```

Second table is `tbl_revenue` which contains revenue values for specific date.

```
table: tbl_revenue
date date
revenue bigint

example content:
2014-01-10 | 10
2015-01-22 | 10
```

Now we want to apply percent specified in table `tbl_percents` to revenue. In result we want to get something like this:

```
2014-01-10 | 1 #because from 2001-01-01 to 2015-01-21 percent = 10%
2015-01-22 | 2 #because from 2015-01-22 till now percent = 20%
```

Is it possible to get this result in single SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. You want to do a join using a BETWEEN condition. I have to caution you that these types of queries get very expensive, very fast, so you don't want to do this on a huge dataset. That being said, you can join your tables with something like the following:

```
SELECT b.revenue, a.percent
FROM tbl_percents AS a
INNER JOIN tbl_revenue AS b
ON b.date BETWEEN a.from_date AND 
     CASE WHEN a.to_date = DATE("0000-00-00") THEN DATE("2100-01-01")
          ELSE a.to_date END
```

Basically what I'm doing is setting the to_date to something very large and in the future (namely Jan 01, 2100). If the to_date is 0000-00-00, then I apply the very large in the future date. Otherwise I just use the to_date. Using that, I join by revenue date to my percents table where the revenue date is between the percent start date and my modified percent end date.

Again, this is computationally not a good idea on a huge dataset... but for general purposes, it should work just fine. If you start having trouble with speed/performance, I'd suggest trying to apply similar logic using a scripting language like R or Python.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT (CAST(COALESCE(SELECT [percent] FROM tbl_percents 
  WHERE tbl_revenue.[date] BETWEEN TO AND FROM OR [date] > TO 
  AND FROM = '0000-00-00' LIMIT 1),0) AS DECIMAL(12,2)) / 100) * revenue
  AS MyNewVal FROM tbl_revenue
```

I can't test this where I am, but it might get you pointed in a good direction.   I think you need to cast your int stored [percent] field to decimal to avoid 10/100==0 but it seems strait forward otherwise.